# Why html_nodes gives {xml_nodeset (0)}

Tags: css, r, screen-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the coinbase pro to get the coin's name. *html_nodes* returns *{xml_nodeset (0)}*. Any idea how can I fix this issue?

website: https://pro.coinbase.com/markets

selectorGagate `.dOEGza`

inspect tag: *xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "dOEGza", " " ))]'*

```
url = "https://pro.coinbase.com/markets"
pg <- read_html(url)
html_nodes(pg, '.dOEGza')

{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

even using xpath:

```
html_nodes(pg, xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "dOEGza", " " ))]')
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting no results from that url because the results you see on the webpage are pulled from requests the browser makes dynamically, through running JavaScript, which update the page with additional content. With `rvest` there is no JavaScript engine to run JavaScript, so you only get the static content from the initial URI.

Rather than searching for APIs/XHRs within the browser network tab, for the endpoint possibly providing the dynamic content, it is more appropriate, and robust, to use the APIs provided for the service where available.

In this case, it looks like **there is a free public API for that data**.

See this endpoint returning products as json

```
https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products
```

From the documentation:

> PUBLIC ENDPOINTS
>
> We throttle public endpoints by IP: 10 requests per second, up to 15
> requests per second in bursts. Some endpoints may have custom rate
> limits.

Read more:

https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#introduction